# почему при отправке двух одинаковых гет запросовс одинаковым телом я получаю разные ответы сервера?

Tags: visual-studio, c++

вот часть кода которая делает запрос

```
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
    stream.connect("www.mail.ru","http");
stream << "GET /cgi-bin/msglist HTTP/1.1\r\n";
stream << "Host: e.mail.ru\r\n";
stream << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
stream << "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11\r\n";
stream << "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
stream << "Referer: http://mail.ru/ \r\n";
stream << "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n";
stream << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";
stream << "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n";
stream << "Cookie: куки сдесь\r\n\r\n";
stream.flush();
```

я получаю ответ от сревера ( из программы)HTTP/1.1 302 OK

```
HTTP/1.1 302 OK
Date: Sat, 14 Jul 2012 14:15:03 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix) mru_xml/0.471 gorgona/2.1 mod_jk/1.2.4 mod_ruby/1.0
.7 Ruby/1.6.8 mod_mrim/0.17
Connection: close
Location: http://e.mail.ru/cgi-bin/msglist
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
```

а такой ответ я получаю из браузера
 //HTTP/1.1 200 OK

```
//Server: nginx/0.7.62
//Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 18:50:46 GMT
///Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
//Connection: close
//P3P: CP="NON CUR OUR IND UNI INT"
//Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
//Pragma: no-cache
//Expires: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 18:50:46 GMT
//Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 22:50:46 GMT
//X-Host: f306.mail.ru
//Content-Length: 461042
```

Вопрос почему я получаю 302 в места 200 ? чтоя делаю не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

См. [Список кодов состояния HTTP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Код 302 в ответе

```
HTTP/1.1 302 OK
```

это код -  Moved Temporarily («перемещено временно»)

В ответе Вы можете увидеть

```
Location: http://e.mail.ru/cgi-bin/msglist
```

Вот туда надо перенаправить запрос.

Comment: Но я же уже обрашюсь к нему?

Comment: Вы обращаетесь по адресу "www.mail.ru".

Comment: Cпасибо теперь понятно.тоесть я должен поставить в stream.connect (e.mail.ru/cgi-bin/msglist,http) а в stream <<"GET / http \r\n" ; Так?

Comment: IMHO в stream.connect("e.mail.ru","http"),

а GET оставить /cgi-bin/msglist

Вообще ncat-ом можете попробовать.